# Calling action from custom view (xib) inside another xib

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

My blueprint is like this:

- I have a `UIViewController` that loads a Xib (Main.xib).
- This xib has a `UIView` pointing to another custom view created from
  xib (Header.xib).

If I create a button inside Main.xib and add an action to my `ViewController` (printing) it works ok, since I set the `FileOwner` of Main.xib to ViewController.swift. However, in `Header.xib` I have another button that I want also to be able to connect to my `ViewController`, but I get the following error despite i also set the file owner to the `ViewController`:

```
2015-03-04 21:49:11.035 Testing[25795:1041547] -[Testing.Header printing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9de0d40dc0
2015-03-04 21:49:11.040 Testing[25795:1041547] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Testing.Header printing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9de0d40dc0'
```

**First throw call stack:**

Any ideas?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Main", owner: self, options: nil).first as UIView
    }

    @IBAction func printing(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("Testing action")
    }

}

class Header: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Header", owner: self, options: nil).first as UIView
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }
}
```

[image: Info]
[image: Info2]
If anyone is more interested I also give a link to the test project I made:
[Link to a test project](http://www.ruiznadal.com/test_xib.zip)

Comment: http://www.ruiznadal.com/test_xib.zip